# Finding nested array to store new data in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm new to Vue and Vuex and I'm trying to create a simple todo app where the user should be able to create projects that has their own collections of todos. The todos for each project are then categorized into **initial**, **WIP** and **finished**. A project is viewable through the route `projects/:id`, where `id` is the id of the project. My structure in the Vuex store for each project is as follows:

```
{
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    description: "Lorem ipsum",
    id: "99149129492149214",
    todos: {
        initial: [
        {
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            createdBy: "Tobias",
            id: "99149129492149215",
        }
        ],
        wip: [
        {
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            createdBy: "Tobias",
            id: "99149129492149216",
        }
        ],
        finished: []
    }
}
```

I want to create this function that lets the user create a new todo in a project by clicking a button. The project should then be added to the `todos.initial` array with the same object structure that each todo follows.

I know how to for example create a new project. I would then just create a method in the `Projects.vue` that, using an action and a mutation in Vuex, pushes the state of the `projects` array in the store with the data for the new project. For this I don't have to specify anything other than what array to push the data to.

However, what I need help with understanding is how to tell Vuex to push an array within the project that I clicked the "add todo" button on. For example, if the user is viewing the project with the route `projects/99149129492149214` and the user clicks the "add todo" button, I want a new todo to be pushed to the `todos.initial` array of that specific project.

What are the best practices for this? I'm thinking that I might have to pass the ID of the currently viewed project to the mutation method, but I don't know how this is done right.

Answer (score 0):

I am still learning about Vuex as well, so hopefully my answer will be able to help you.

If your route is `projects/:id`, you can easily get the id by `this.$route.params.id` in your 'Add Todo' method. Then you can pass the id into your mutation, and search the projects by id.

Your method:

```
methods: {
   submitInitialTodo() {
      // your mutation for Vuex
      this.addInitialTodo(this.$route.params.id);
   }
}
```

In your mutation:

```
mutations: {
   addInitialTodo(state, project_id) {
      // search project list by id and push to array
   }
}
```